# What is the correct mysql query to perform a join and a count?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table, one holds information about images and the other contains information about comments agains the images.

I need to have a query that shows the count of comments against an image in one query. I have tried the below:

```
SELECT l.img_id, COUNT(c.comment_id) AS comment_count FROM tbl_images l, tbl_image_comments c WHERE l.img_id = c.img_id;
```

but this doesnt report correctly as it just counts all of the comments table.

Can anyone help please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing here is making a `CROSS JOIN` of the images and comments tables: each row from images gets "paired" with *all* the rows from comments and vice versa (this explains the comment count), and then you filter on the resulting dataset with the `WHERE` clause.

What you *should* be doing is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which "pairs" each row from images *only with those rows from comments which fulfil a specific condition*:

```
SELECT l.img_id, COUNT(c.comment_id) AS comment_count
FROM tbl_images l
LEFT JOIN tbl_image_comments c ON l.img_id = c.img_id
```

Comment: OK this is what i ended up using -> SELECT l.img_id, COUNT(c.comment_id) AS comment_count FROM tbl_images as l LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_image_comments AS c USING (img_id) GROUP BY l.img_id;

Comment: @Jon: you forgot the `GROUP BY ...`

Comment: @Tony: Why did you put `GROUP BY` in there?

Comment: @Jon it seemed to work (dont i need it then?) :) I do have another issue though, i need to have a second count from a different table again, any idea on the syntax for that?

Comment: @Tony: Don't just put stuff in there without knowing why you do it. For the second count you need to provide more information. Consider asking a separate question for it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify a grouping for the count to work as you expect.

try adding

```
GROUP BY l.img_id
```

on the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

as the option:

```
SELECT 
  l.img_id, 
  (select COUNT(*) from  tbl_image_comments c l.img_id = c.img_id) AS comment_count 
FROM 
  tbl_images l;
```